# jQuery-UI: On click move draggable to top like dialog

Tags: jquery-ui

When one clicks on a jQuery-UI dialog, it is automatically moved on top of any other UI element. How can this behavior be duplicated for jQuery-UI draggables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it approximately with the stack option:

```
stack: '.ui-dialog'
```

It doesn't work on click, though. Anyway, sometimes it does help to look at the docs. ;-)